# Range filter for custom attribute in magento

Tags: php, magento, filter

I need range filter for custom attribute (weight) like price range filter

i used below url for price range filter

```
domain/rings?&price=20000-30000 - working
```

same like that i used for weight range filter

```
domain/rings?&weight=-400-500 - not working
```

how can i solve this issue?

Please suggest any idea to filter weight range

Answer (score 2):

For changing attribute type without deleting it For that you can make .php file on root folder of your magento and put the below code and run the file after making desire changes.

```
<?php
    require_once '../app/Mage.php';
    Mage::app();
    $installer = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
    $entityTypeId = $installer->getEntityTypeId('catalog_product');
    // replace <my_attribute_code> with your attribute code
   $idAttribute = $installer->getAttribute($entityTypeId,     '<my_attribute_code>', 'attribute_id');
   $installer->updateAttribute($entityTypeId, $idAttribute, array(
   'frontend_input' => 'text',
   'backend_type' => 'decimal',
   ));
  // let's see if it worked
  $attribute =  Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('catalog_product', '<my_attribute_code>');
  Zend_Debug::dump($attribute->getData()); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set Use In Layered Navigation to 'Filterable (with results)'

Set Use In Search Results Layered Navigation to "Yes" for weight attribute.

Comment: Ok. But note that Magento allows to filter by decimal attributes (like price) and dropdown attributes. What is the type of `weight` attribute ?

Comment: input type is textbox  so i can't set  Use In Layered Navigation to 'Filterable (with results)'

Comment: Ohh. Ok. So I think you need to change it's type

Comment: how can i change the type without delete attribute